# Photo printing in C#

Tags: c#, printing

I have the following `C#` code to print `8x6` photos in a desktop application.

It works on regular printer with regular letter size paper.
But my client is using kodak printer with `8x6` paper, the photos are printing but their size is different, they are not printing in full `8x6` size, I'm doing something wrong.

Can someone please guide me in right direction.

```
public void Print(List ListToBePrinted)
{
    PrintDialog SelectedPrinter = new PrintDialog();
    if (SelectedPrinter.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        PrintCapabilities printerCapabilities = SelectedPrinter.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities();
        Size PageSize = new Size(printerCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, printerCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
        Size PrintableImageSize = new Size();
        foreach (Uri aUri in ListToBePrinted)
        {
            DrawingVisual drawVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
            imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(aUri);
            imageBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
            imageBrush.TileMode = TileMode.None;
            imageBrush.AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Center;
            imageBrush.AlignmentY = AlignmentY.Center;
            if (imageBrush.ImageSource.Width > imageBrush.ImageSource.Height)
                PrintableImageSize = new Size(768, 576); //8x6
            else PrintableImageSize = new Size(576, 768); //6x8 
            double xcor = 0; double ycor = 0;
            if (imageBrush.ImageSource.Width > imageBrush.ImageSource.Height)
            {
                if ((PageSize.Width - PrintableImageSize.Height) > 0)
                    xcor = (PageSize.Width - PrintableImageSize.Height) / 2;
                if ((PageSize.Height - PrintableImageSize.Width) > 0)
                    ycor = (PageSize.Height - PrintableImageSize.Width) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((PageSize.Width - PrintableImageSize.Width) > 0)
                    xcor = (PageSize.Width - PrintableImageSize.Width) / 2;
                if ((PageSize.Height - PrintableImageSize.Height) > 0)
                    ycor = (PageSize.Height - PrintableImageSize.Height) / 2;
            }
            using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawVisual.RenderOpen())
            {
                if (imageBrush.ImageSource.Width > imageBrush.ImageSource.Height)
                {
                    drawingContext.PushTransform(new RotateTransform(90, PrintableImageSize.Width / 2, PrintableImageSize.Height / 2));
                }
                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(imageBrush, null, new Rect(xcor, ycor, PrintableImageSize.Width, PrintableImageSize.Height));
            }
            SelectedPrinter.PrintVisual(drawVisual, "Print");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @digEmAll: that was some speedy edit!

Comment: @Nick: god bless Visual Studio auto-format feature ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the HardMarginX and HardMarginY values, if you can find them.

I have this code in one of my apps (where e is a PrintPageEventArgs)

```
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(nextImage, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.X - e.PageSettings.HardMarginX, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Y - e.PageSettings.HardMarginY, e.PageSettings.Landscape ? e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height : e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, e.PageSettings.Landscape ? e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width : e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height);
```

My printing function is a bit primitive, but maybe you can adjust your xcor and ycor based on the hard margins.

Comment: Can I use 0,0 for xcor and ycor if I want to print full page? I tried it but it doesn't seem working

Comment: I tried 0,0 for xcor and ycor and all margins to 0. even then there are tiny margins around the photo. How can I get borderless prints?